# Automation of reading data from excel and pasting it in web form

Tags: excel, forms, automation

I want to read from an excel file and copy the relevant data into a web form in the browser. I also need to check some conditions before pasting the data in the page according to the data in my excel sheet. How can I achieve that? What tool I can use to achieve the desired result?

Using Javascript may be fine, but I am looking for some kind of windows automation tools as in autohotkey to do the job.

Comment: Which language/technology do you wish to use? - This question is unclear and bound to have many ways of doing things. - This question might get closed if you don't provide additional information

Comment: I have added some additional info which can help you figure this out more clearly.